# How do I add the NUMBERS in a string? (C)

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to add all the numbers in a string in the C language. For example, 12abc4 should yield 16 (12+4). Can you help me complete it?

My code as of now is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function(char a[])
{
    char sum=0;
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>='a'&&a[i]<='z')
        {
            continue;

        }
        else
        {
            if(a[i+1]>='a'&&a[i+1]<='z')
            {
                sum=sum+a[i];
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%c",sum);

}

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        char a[100001];
        scanf("%s",a);
        function(a);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `scanf("%s", a);` makes your program [vulnerable to buffer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621394/6865932), though your buffer is quite large, to avoid this use a limit in the specifier:  `scanf("%100000s", a);`. In the link there are also better methods to safely read `stdin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. First, you are confusing the `char` type (a representation of a printable *character*, such as the **digit** `'3'`) and the `int` type (representing the *actual value* of a number, and stored as a binary value). In your code, you are attempting to sum the *former*, where (assuming ASCII representation), the *character* `2` will have a value of `50`. We can readily address this issue by simply subtracting the value of the `'0'` character (ASCII `48`), as the C Standard **guarantees** that the digits will be represented by consecutive, increasing values.

Another problem is that your code will add each *individual* digit, so that the `12` in your string will be summed up as `1 + 2`, rather than as `12`. To get round this, we can keep a 'flag' to keep track of whether we are currently 'inside' a number and, if so, first multiply our *current* number by 10, before adding the new digit.

Also, rather than checking a specific range of non-digit characters, you should use the standard `isdigit()` function to check if a character is (not) a decimal number.

There are also a few other issues in your code, which I have addressed in the comments in the "working version" posted below:

```c
#include <stdio.h> // This header for "printf" and "scanf"
#include <ctype.h> // This one for the "isdigit" function!

void function(char a[])
{
//  char sum = 0; // Let's use an int for the sum!
    int sum = 0, add = 0; // ... and another one for each extracted number to add
//  int count = 0; // This is never used
    int in_number = 0; // We need a flag to see if we're currently processing a number
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    //  if (a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z') {
        if (!isdigit(a[i])) { // This is better than testing individual character ranges!
            if (in_number) { // We have a number to add to our total...
                sum += add;
            }
            add = 0; // Reset the 'next' number to add
            in_number = 0; // and clear our 'in_number' flag
        //  continue; // We don't need this, because the "else" block won't run if we're in here!
        }
        else { // We've found a digit ...
            add *= 10; // First, multiply our current number by 10 (before we add the next digit)
            add += a[i] - '0'; // We need to convert the character to a number
            in_number = 1; // Don't forget to set our flag to show we're currently in a number!
        }
    }
    // When we've finished our loop, we need to check if we're still inside a number:
    if (in_number) {
        sum += add;
    }
    printf("%d", sum); // Use the "%d" format to print an integer!
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        char a[1000]; // DO you REALLY need a 10001 character buffer?
        scanf("%s", a);
        function(a);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0; // Always good practice to actually have this at the end of your "main"
}
```

Feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Though the buffer is large there is a risk of overflow with `scanf("%s", a);`, it's a `gets` like problem.

Comment: @anastaciu A fair comment, indeed! I was just trying to simplify and reduce the code to address the *obvious* issues in the code. But your comment is well-made, and I shall consider editing my post (after I have had much-needed sleep)!

Comment: Ah yes, the rest of the warrior :) I already left a comment in the answer so I think we can consider it solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read digits and convert them as you go through the string, as shown here:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int sum_numbers(char *s)
{
        int accum = 0;
        int number = 0;
        int c;
        while ((c = *s++) != 0) {
                if (isdigit(c)) {
                        number *= 10;
                        number += c - '0';
                } else {
                        accum += number;
                        number = 0;
                }
        }
        accum += number;
        return accum;
}
```

A complete program, that runs the algorithm on each argument passed as parameter on the command line, is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int sum_numbers(char *s)
{
        int accum = 0;
        int number = 0;
        int c;
        while ((c = *s++) != 0) {
                if (isdigit(c)) {
                        number *= 10;
                        number += c - '0';
                } else {
                        accum += number;
                        number = 0;
                }
        }
        accum += number;
        return accum;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
                printf("argv[%d] = \"%s\", sum=%d\n",
                        i, argv[i], sum_numbers(argv[i]));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

same program, but reading input from stdin:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int sum_numbers(char *s)
{
        int accum = 0;
        int number = 0;
        int c;
        while ((c = *s++) != 0) {
                if (isdigit(c)) {
                        number *= 10;
                        number += c - '0';
                } else {
                        accum += number;
                        number = 0;
                }
        }
        accum += number;
        return accum;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int i = 0;
        char buffer[1000];

        while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
                /* get out the final \n, if present. */
                char *s = strtok(buffer, "\n");
                printf("argv[%d] = \"%s\", sum=%d\n",
                        ++i, s, sum_numbers(s));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

As you see, only the `main()` routine changes, the calculations goes the same for each of the three programs.